# Finding max and min from polynomial equation

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$ and $b \geqslant 0$. Given that $x^4 + ax^2 + b = 0$ has $2$ real solutions, find maximum for $|a-b|$ and minimum for $a+2b$.

My solution :
$$x^4+ax^2+b=0 \implies (x^2-c)(x^2-d) = 0$$

there is only 1 case which is possible,that is, both $c$ and $d$ are positive

so $x^2=c$ and $x^2 = d$

if it has 2 real solutions, then $c = d$ ($x=\pm\sqrt c$  and   $ x=\pm\sqrt d$). So we get $a=-2c$ , $b=c^2$

$$|a-b|=|-2c-c^2|=c^2+2c+1-1=(c+1)^2-1$$
but I can't find max.

$$a+2b = 2c^2-2c = 2(c-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{2}\implies \min = -\frac{1}{2}$$

But I think my method is wrong because I can't solve for $\max$.

Comment: sorry, question is edited @RodrigodeAzevedo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b=0$ and $a\geq 0$ then  $x^4+ax^2+b=0$ has just one real root, i.e. $x=0$.

If $b=0$ and $a< 0$ then  $x^4+ax^2+b=0$ has three real roots, i.e. $x=0, \pm\sqrt{-a}$

If $b>0$ then $x^4+ax^2+b=0$ has two distinct real roots iff $z^2+az+b=0$ has one positive root and a negative root, which is impossible because $b>0$, or two coincident positive roots that is when $\Delta=a^2-4b=0$ and $a<0$.

Hence for $b=a^2/4$ with $a<0$ we have that $|a-b|=|a-a^2/4|$ has supremum $+\infty$, whereas $a+2b=a+a^2/2=\frac{(a+1)^2-1}{2}$ has minimum value $-1/2$, attained for $a=-1$.

Comment: What are infimum and supremum?

Comment: The "infimum  $0$" means that that $0$ cannot be attained but there are positive values arbitrary close to $0$. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: so |a-b| has no maximum?

Comment: No maximum, consider $a=-n$ and $b=a^2/4$, then  $x^4 + ax^2 + a^2/2 =(2x^2-n)^2/4= 0$ has two real roots  and $|a-b|=n+n^2/4\to +\infty$ a s $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: just got exact question, it wasn't |a-b|. It was a symbol similar to absolute symbol like find maximum of  $|r|$ if $|r|$ is number that is more than or equal to r.

so the answer for a-b with this symbol is $0$ ?

Comment: actually just found it, it was ceil function